# When meeting someone and you are glad to see them

Tags: перевод, грамматика

When meeting someone and you are glad to see them I have learned that one phrase that can be used is:
"Я радa видеть вас"

When you want to respond to that and tell that you are also happy to see them would: "Я также рад видеть вас" be a appropriate response?

Comment: “Lieutenant, is that your sword or are you just glad to see me?”

Comment: yes, it is an appropriate response, and very polite (fits well when meeting for the first time or when you intend to sound formal or official); the informal variant would be "Я рад тебя видеть – Я тоже рад тебя видеть" (good for close friends or in a company of peers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a single word used quite often in such cases: "взаимно". That words is used when you want to express that you share the same feelings with person after he or she expressed that feelings. It could be used both for positive and negative sentiments. For instance:

> Пётр: Как же я тебя ненавижу!
>
> Василий: Знаешь, взаимно.

As of your phrase "я так же рад видеть вас" (notice that "так же" in this case is written separately) - it is a valid but slightly non-colloquial form. It sounds a bit pathetic. Something like "и я тоже очень рад" sounds more natural.

Comment: And don't forget about the gender, if you're female, e. g.: "Я тоже очень рада."

Comment: What do you mean by "pathetic"? )

Comment: @VCH250 I guess the closest in Russian will be "вычурный" (in this context)

Comment: I meant, what do you mean in English by the use of that word. I just wanted a clarification))

Comment: @shabunc, are you sure about the spelling of *также* here? in this sentance *также* = *тоже*, so it is spelled in one word; please, correct